# Как сделать простую карусель из картинок?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Как можно сделать простую карусель из картинок? Спасибо!

```css
#slider {
    width: 600px;
    height: 300px;
}

#items img {
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="slider">
    <div id="items">
        <img src="https://s.0532.ua/section/newsIcon/upload/images/news/icon/000/034/596/1-0130_5b194acf04f1f.jpg" />
        <img src="https://images.prismic.io/zalando-jobsite/95a8794954c6b36dc6cf6c9f5a9994be7f47575d_stocksnap_6yechnhrsw.jpg?auto=compress,format" />
        <img src="https://mp3party.net/system/boxes/imgs/000/000/369/large/large_thumb-wz2opf.png" />
        <img src="https://sfera.az/file/pic/xeber/2019-09/1569402140_1546350277_hava-yagmursuz.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
<button id="prev">Назад</button>
<button id="next">Вперед</button>
```

Comment: https://webformyself.com/kak-sozdat-karusel-ispolzuya-tolko-html-i-css/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Вариант с навигацией*

```js
var count_elements = 4,
  current_element = 0,
  width = 400,
  height = 200,
  duration = 500;
var screen = $('#items');
screen.width(width * count_elements);
function move_screen(x) {
  current_element = (current_element + x) % count_elements;
  if (current_element < 0) {
    current_element += count_elements;
  }
  //console.log(current_element);
  screen.animate({
    marginLeft: -width * current_element
  }, duration);
}
$("#prev").click(function() {
  move_screen(-1);
})
$("#next").click(function() {
  move_screen(1);
})
```

```css
#slider {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#items img {
  float: left;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slider">
  <div id="items">
    <img src="https://s.0532.ua/section/newsIcon/upload/images/news/icon/000/034/596/1-0130_5b194acf04f1f.jpg" />
    <img src="https://images.prismic.io/zalando-jobsite/95a8794954c6b36dc6cf6c9f5a9994be7f47575d_stocksnap_6yechnhrsw.jpg?auto=compress,format" />
    <img src="https://mp3party.net/system/boxes/imgs/000/000/369/large/large_thumb-wz2opf.png" />
    <img src="https://sfera.az/file/pic/xeber/2019-09/1569402140_1546350277_hava-yagmursuz.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
<button id="prev">Назад</button>
<button id="next">Вперед</button>
```

*Вариант с навигацией + автоматическое перелистывание слайдов*

```js
$(function() {
  var count_elements = 4,
    current_element = 0,
    width = 400,
    height = 200,
    duration = 500,
    pause = 1800,
    auto = false;
  var screen = $('#items');
  screen.width(width * count_elements);

  function move_screen(x) {
    current_element = (current_element + x + count_elements) % count_elements;
    var time = auto ? pause : 0;
    screen.delay(time).animate({
      marginLeft: -width * current_element
    }, duration, function() {
      if (auto) move_screen(x);
    });
  }
  $("#prev").click(function() {
    auto = false;
    move_screen(-1);
    $("#auto").toggleClass("act", auto);
  })
  $("#next").click(function() {
    auto = false;
    move_screen(1);
    $("#auto").toggleClass("act", auto);
  })
  $("#auto").click(function() {
    auto = !auto;
    auto ? move_screen(1) : screen.stop();
    $("#auto").toggleClass("act", auto);
  })

});
```

```css
#slider {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#items img {
  float: left;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slider">
  <div id="items">
    <img src="https://s.0532.ua/section/newsIcon/upload/images/news/icon/000/034/596/1-0130_5b194acf04f1f.jpg" />
    <img src="https://images.prismic.io/zalando-jobsite/95a8794954c6b36dc6cf6c9f5a9994be7f47575d_stocksnap_6yechnhrsw.jpg?auto=compress,format" />
    <img src="https://mp3party.net/system/boxes/imgs/000/000/369/large/large_thumb-wz2opf.png" />
    <img src="https://sfera.az/file/pic/xeber/2019-09/1569402140_1546350277_hava-yagmursuz.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
<button id="prev">Назад</button>
<button id="next">Вперед</button>
<button id="auto">Авто</button>
```

Comment: а сможешь сделать переключение по времени - к примеру через 0.5s ?

Comment: к примеру как slick.js - если не кликать он сам листается

Comment: ни чего страшного ..